# Swift reduce on array is orders of magnitude slower than unsafe reduce

Tags: swift, optimization, reduce

In my program I heavily rely in the following pattern that I think is very common. There is a structure that holds data (lets say `Double`):

```swift
struct Container {
  var data: Double
}
```

Next, an array of that struct is created, potentially big:

```swift
let containers = (0...<10_000_000).map { _ in 
  Container(data: .random(in: -10...10))
}
```

Then, a (map)reduce operation is applied to the array to extract a value, for instance:

```swift
let sum = containers.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.data }
```

---

I first thought that this particular operation would be fast because the operation is simple enough for the compiler to optimize bounds checks and other slow operations: there is no weird index computations, no capture in the closure, everything is immutable, etc...

But then, I compared performance against this unsafe implementation of reduce on arrays:

```swift
extension Array {
  func unsafeReduce<Result>(
    _ initialResult: Result,
    _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result
  ) rethrows -> Result {
    try self.withUnsafeBufferPointer { buffer -> Result in
      try buffer.reduce(initialResult, nextPartialResult)
    }
  }
}
```

I compiled both programs with full optimizations `-O -unchecked` and I also used Xcode profiler to time programs, **it appears that the unsafe reduce is 16x faster than its safe counterpart:** 200ms vs 4s.

My questions are:

- First, is my unsafe implementation right? What are the potential issued in using this version?
- What is the cause of the slowdown? I tried to have a look at the assembly code with Compiler Explorer and with Xcode profiler's call tree but can't figure out what is the exact cause. Can someone explain step by step what exactly the program does?

---

I'm using Xcode 11.5 with Swift 5 on a MacBook Air mid-2015.

---

### Edit

I ported the code to Python and without using Numpy for any computation it is still 2 times faster than Swift `reduce` operation. I did not check the memory consumption, though.

Comment: It might be because of the fact that Array is a value type and struct is also a value type in swift. When you try to modify the value at specific index in array lets say `myArray[10] = someNewStruct` you expect it to be a single operation but in hindsight it actually performs 3 operations. 1. read the value at `myArray[10]` 2. copy the value at `myArray[10]` to temp location because array is value type so it cant mutate it. 3. change the value and come back and check if someone holds a original value at `myArray[10]` if not then replace with this new modified value.

Comment: Though this never actually happens in array, this is how it happens in Dictionary. Array uses specific optimised technique called `mutableAddressWithPinnedNativeOwner` where it actually access the value at specific index, means though array is value type it breaks the rule here and actually gets the pointer to value at specific index and modifies it directly, may be `unsafeReduce` makes the same operation much efficient way. There is a proposal for modify accessor in swift forum which explains this issue with value type mutation while looping through it

Comment: read : https://forums.swift.org/t/modify-accessors/31872

Comment: What's strange is that everything is immutable in my code, why the compiler would copy the array element to a temp location for computations ? the value will never change, there is no need for atomic operations or other memory safe tricks.

Comment: How is this different from the example in the docs? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994771-withunsafebufferpointer

Comment: It's similar excepting small details like the stride 2 iteration, what is your point ?

Comment: My point is they tell you the answer, direct indexing without bounds checking is fast. `reduce` is implemented using `for element in self`, you are removing all the overhead of that.

Comment: That is not what I understand from the doc, it says that "Often, the optimiser can eliminate bounds checks" and in this simple situation it is expected to be the case, there is no chance to be out of bounds as I'm using the iterator provided by `reduce`.

Comment: I think I found the issue btw: even though I compile in release mode with full optimisations it does not apply optimisations (even when profiling and testing). I need to turn on optimisations for the target in addition to the optimisations for the project.